# Hook a function based on adding a particular product in Woo

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create an action hook based on a particular product being added to the Woocommerce cart:

When PRODUCT-#123 is added to the cart, then doThisFunction();

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your theme's functions.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );

function custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id ) {
    // replace 123 with a valid product ID 
    if( 123 == $product_id ) {
        //call the desired function 
    }
}
```